# Black screen when UEFI installing Ubuntu Server 16.04 on GTX 1060 laptop

Tags: server, uefi

I can see the install menu:

[image: GRUB menu with Install Ubuntu Server highlighted]

But after I chose "Install Ubuntu Server", the screen [went black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcLfq.jpg) forever.

What should I try?

Comment: @Zanna GTX 1060 Laptop, Clevo motherboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this by switching **MSHybrid** or **DISCRETE SWITCH** from **MSHybrid** to **DISCRETE** in BIOS.